# Adding Label underneath UIBarButtonItem like in UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Basically I want to achieve this using `UIBarButton`:

[image]

I tried using `setTitle` but I end up having something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom navigation bar - add UIView to top of your viewcontroller, and add UIButton in left corner of it. And label underneath button.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by using custom view with UIBarButtonItem. Something like this.

**Swift**

```
let image = UIImage.init(named: "image_name")
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
button.setTitle("title", for: .normal)
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
```